# Keep getting an error when trying to create a foreign key in sql?

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

CREATE TABLE Room (
RoomID nvarchar(8) PRIMARY KEY,
Capacity numeric(3)

)

CREATE TABLE RoomType (
RoomType nvarchar(2) primary key,
Description nvarchar(20),
Responsiblity nvarchar(20)
)

alter table Room

add constraint fk_type foreign key (Type) references RoomType(Type)

Major Error 0x80040E11, Minor Error 0

> alter table Room
>   add constraint fk_type foreign key (Type) references RoomType(Type)
>   Invalid column ID. [ Type ]

Comment: What do you want to name the table you are trying to create? What fields do you want in that table? What tables and fields should participate in foreign key relationship?

Comment: I want the RoomID and Equipmenttype in the table i am going to create to associate Room with equipment so the new table will be called RoomEquipment. @zedfoxus

Comment: Okay, RoomEquipment is the table. It will have RoomID and EquipmentType fields. RoomEquipment's EquipmentType field will be related to Equipment's EquipmentType field. Will RoomEquipment's RoomID field relate to anything?

Comment: Yes the RoomID field relates to the Room table. @zedfoxus

Comment: Omg I forgot to add the table for Room.

Comment: The RoomID relates to another table called Room which I forgot to add. @zedfoxus

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create a table RoomEquipment that combines RoomID and EquipmentType like this:

```
create table RoomEquipment (
  RoomID int,
  EquipmentType nvarchar(1),
  primary key (roomid, equipmenttype),
  constraint fk_roomequipment_equipment_type 
             foreign key (equipmenttype) 
             references equipment(equipmenttype),
  constraint fk_roomequipment_equipment_roomid
             foreign key (roomid) 
             references room(roomid)
);
```

Other tables may look like this:

```
-- I prefer using char datatype for predictable number of characters in a field
CREATE TABLE RoomType (
Roomtype nvarchar(2) NOT NULL,
Description nvarchar(20),
Responsibility nvarchar(20),
primary key (Roomtype)
);

-- You could use char(1) instead of nvarchar(1) for type; I'd prefer using int instead
create table Equipment (
Equipmenttype nvarchar(1) NOT NULL,
Description nvarchar(10)
);

-- Added a unique key to assist with good foreign key relationship
alter table Equipment add constraint uk_equipment_equipmenttype unique (equipmenttype);

-- Just use an int or char if roomID length is predictable
Create table Room (
RoomID nvarchar(8),
Capacity numeric(3),
Roomtype(fk,nvarchar(2)
);

alter table room add constraint uk_room_id unique (roomid);
```

Example is here: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/f510b

Comment: I have added the table Room.

Comment: Check the first block of code where I create `RoomEquipment` table with appropriate foreign keys. Does this work for you?

Comment: In my assignment it says we aren't allowed to combine any tables but this does help thanks.

Comment: Glad it is helpful. The updated SQLFiddle example is here for future reference: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/22731